# Irregular grouping of timestamp variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table organized as follows:

```
id       lateAt
1231235  2019/09/14
1242123  2019/09/13
3465345  NULL
5676548  2019/09/28
8986475  2019/09/23
```

Where `lateAt` is a timestamp of when a certain loan's payment became late. So, for each current date - I need to look at these numbers daily - there's a certain amount of entries which are late for 0-15, 15-30, 30-45, 45-60, 60-90 and 90+ days.

This is my desired output:

```
lateGroup   Count
0-15        20
15-30       22
30-45       25
45-60       32
60-90       47
90+         57
```

This is something I can easily calculate in R, but to get the results back to my BI dashboard I'd have to create a new table in my database, which I don't think is a good practice. What is the SQL-native approach to this problem?

Comment: So the "late group" is calculated by the difference between today and the `lateat` column? So `id = 1231235`  would fall into the group 30-45 because that's 32 days late today (2019-10-16)

Comment: I'm using postgresql and your second comment is right.

Comment: Your groups overlap.  Should an id that is 15 days late be in the 0-15 group or the 15-30 group or (doubtful) both?

Comment: Good point. It's supposed to be inclusive on the infimum and exclusive on the supremum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this in SQL is:

```
SELECT '0-15'   AS lateGroup, 
       COUNT(*) AS lateGroupCount
FROM my_table t
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) >= 0
  AND (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) <  15

UNION

SELECT '15-30'  AS lateGroup, 
       COUNT(*) AS lateGroupCount
FROM my_table t
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) >= 15
  AND (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) <  30

UNION

SELECT '30-45'  AS lateGroup, 
       COUNT(*) AS lateGroupCount
FROM my_table t
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) >= 30
  AND (CURRENT_DATE - t.lateAt) <  45

-- Etc...
```

For production code, you would want to do something more like Ross' answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would define the "late groups" using a [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html), the join against the number of days:

```
with groups (grp) as (
  values 
    (int4range(0,15, '[)')),
    (int4range(15,30, '[)')),
    (int4range(30,45, '[)')),
    (int4range(45,60, '[)')),
    (int4range(60,90, '[)')),
    (int4range(90,null, '[)'))
)
select grp, count(t.user_id)
from groups g
  left join the_table t on g.grp @> current_date - t.late_at
group by grp
order by grp;
```

`int4range(0,15, '[)')` creates a range from `0` (inclusive) and `15` (exclusive)

Online example: https://rextester.com/QJSN89445

Comment: I sure wish SQL Server had ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which DBMS you're using, but nearly all of them will have a construct known as a "value constructor" like this:

```
select bins.lateGroup, bins.minVal, bins.maxVal FROM
    (VALUES 
        ('0-15',0,15),
        ('15-30',15.0001,30),  -- increase by a small fraction so bins don't overlap
        ('30-45',30.0001,45),
        ('45-60',45.0001,60),
        ('60-90',60.0001,90),
        ('90-99999',90.0001,99999)
    ) AS bins(lateGroup,minVal,maxVal)
```

If your DBMS doesn't have it, then you can probably use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT '0-15' as lateGroup, 0 as minVal, 15 as maxVal
union all SELECT '15-30',15,30
union all SELECT '30-45',30,45
```

Then your complete query, with the sample data you provided, would look like this:

```
--- example from SQL Server 2012 SP1
--- first let's set up some sample data
create table #temp (id int, lateAt datetime);
INSERT #temp (id, lateAt) values
   (1231235,'2019-09-14'),
   (1242123,'2019-09-13'),
   (3465345,NULL),
   (5676548,'2019-09-28'),
   (8986475,'2019-09-23');
   
--- here's the actual query
select lateGroup, count(*) as Count
from #temp as T,
    (VALUES
        ('0-15',0,15),
        ('15-30',15.0001,30),  -- increase by a small fraction so bins don't overlap
        ('30-45',30.0001,45),
        ('45-60',45.0001,60),
        ('60-90',60.0001,90),
        ('90-99999',90.0001,99999)
    ) AS bins(lateGroup,minVal,maxVal)
    ) AS bins(lateGroup,minVal,maxVal)
where datediff(day,lateAt,getdate()) between minVal and maxVal
group by lateGroup
order by lateGroup

--- remove our sample data
drop table #temp;
```

Here's the output:

```
lateGroup  Count
15-30          2
30-45          2
```

Note: rows with null `lateAt` are not counted.

Comment: If you don't use `between`, then you don't need this "increase by small fraction" part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You're correct of course. It comes down to a choice between undesired verbosities: add a fraction to each upper bound, or duplicate the datediff() part of the expression in the where clause. I find that when the change is the same on each line, repeating it actually *increases* clarity when rereading.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it all in one clear query :

```
with cte_lategroup as
(
    select *
    from (values(0,15,'0-15'),(15,30,'15-30'),(30,45,'30-45')) as t (mini, maxi, designation)
)
select 
    t2.designation
    , count(*)
from test t
    left outer join cte_lategroup t2
    on current_date - t.lateat >= t2.mini
    and current_date - lateat < t2.maxi
group by t2.designation;
```

With a preset like yours :

```
create table test
(
    id int
    , lateAt date
);

insert into test
values (1231235,  to_date('2019/09/14', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
,(1242123,  to_date('2019/09/13', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
,(3465345,  null)
,(5676548,  to_date('2019/09/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
,(8986475,  to_date('2019/09/23', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
```